# Nome dos meses em português e inglês

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

No site em que trabalho, uso a seguinte *query* para mostrar em português as datas que estão armazenadas no banco de dados:

```
$conn->exec("SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT'");
```

Entretanto, descobri que o site passará a ser bilíngue (português e inglês) e preciso mostrar as datas nos dois idiomas. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Não basta fazer um `if` pra mudar o `pt_PT` para `en_US`?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Eu poderia fazer isso, mas esta linha é do arquivo que faz a conexão com o bd. E o include dele nas páginas acontece antes de pegar o idioma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra resolver isto, crie uma página chamada `index.php`, dentro dela, você terá opções de linguagem, apenas bandeiras de cada país por exemplo.

Você terá então uma escolha, que dependendo da escolha você será redirecionado para a mesma página porém com parâmetro diferente, poderia ser usado este código na `index.php` por exemplo:

```html
<a href=pagina_inicial.php?lang=pt_PT >Português</a>
<a href=pagina_inicial.php?lang=en_US >Inglês</a>
```

E então dentro do seu "arquivo que faz conexão com o bd" do qual postou o código na sua pergunta, ele funcionaria da seguinte forma:

```php
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
if ($lang == "pt_PT")
  $conn->exec("SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT'");
else
  $conn->exec("SET lc_time_names = 'en_US'");
```

Você deve estar se perguntando "**Porque eu não simplesmente fiz desta forma?**:"

```php
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$conn->exec("SET lc_time_names = '".$lang."'");
```

**Porque se tornaria um alvo extremamente vulnerável à ataques via SQL Injection**, por isso ficaria muito inseguro(**nunca utilize variáveis que podem ser enviadas pelo usuário dentro de código SQL**)

Desta forma que eu te disse, você consegue saber qual linguagem o usuário quer, no momento da execução do seu comando, via um parâmetro que o mesmo mandou ao escolher qual linguagem na página `index.php`.

Answer (score -3):

Use isso

```
mysql_query('SET lc_time_names = "pt_BR"');
```